# How to run my android application with connection to the ADB?

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, adb

When I try running my application using Android Studio with an USB connection to a physical android phone, it says it's waiting for adb and then it displays the following message:

```
ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'
Errors from ADB:
adb: ADB server didn't ACK
adb: failed to start daemon
```

I tried to *kill* it on terminal using the command:

```
(adb kill-server)
```

And then starting it using the command:

```
(adb start-server)
```

But I am still having the same problem! Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

This problem happend before, but I can't remember how I solved it.

*Notes:
I'm using a Windows 7 machine, the currently isntalled JDK version is* `jdk1.7.0_03`*.*

Comment: temporarily disable all your firewall and anti virus software and see if it made any difference

Comment: I did .. but still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Killing it using the Windows Taskmanager helped me when I had that problem

Comment: How can I restart it back ... just by clicking on the restart button in android studio ?

Comment: Yes. Seems to be stronger than just executing "adb kill-server". You don't have to restart it, just press "Run" in Android Studio afterwards and it will be started automatically.

Comment: Well .. I couldn't find adb.exe in the processes :(

Comment: But I found studio.exe .. shall I end its process and retry ?

Comment: Nothing changed .. I am just so disappointed .. it was working but suddenly, it crashed :'(

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Maybe the port used by adb is used.